# How can I start an azure web job from my site?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am using azure web job for one schedule. I want to make it as on demand format and want to start the job after clicking a button from my site. Is it possible.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Is your sire use .net techologies ?

Comment: Another option that I use to get the same thing with a continuous running webjob is to use the WebJobs SDK QueueTrigger and just need to load a message into the queue to start the logic running.

Answer (score 3):

You could trigger the WebJob via the WebJob API. C# code included in the following post:

http://chriskirby.net/blog/running-your-azure-webjobs-with-the-kudu-api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mysiteslot.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/");
// the creds from my .publishsettings file
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
// POST to the run action for my job
var response = await client.PostAsync("triggeredwebjobs/moJobName/run", null)
```

This would have to be done server side, as you wouldn't want the authorization information being exposed on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebJobs REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to trigger a WebJob.

```
POST /api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run
```

Comment: Non-trivial part is to authenticate to the scm site from the main site. No easy way other than making the publishing creds available (e.g. via app settings).

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Scheduler API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn528946.aspx) is also available. If you trigger the scheduler, which in turn trigger the web job. To Access the scheduler API, you need to have Azure AD credentials with subscription/web app access. It is dynamically provide [WebJob REST APIs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) along with credentials.